# Fast way to sample geometric points from SVG paths

Tags: python, svg

I'm using the excellent `svgpathtools` library in Python 3 to work with some paths in an SVG file, created in a vector drawing application.

I'd like to create detailed point arrays for each of the paths contained within the SVG, where the points are equidistant along the path. The following does just that but becomes unbearably slow if more than a few thousand samples are taken.

```
SAMPLES_PER_PX = 1

fname = "/path/to/file.svg"
paths, attributes = svg2paths(fname)

myPaths = {}
for path,attr in zip(paths, attributes):
    myPathList = []
    pathLength = path.length()
    pathColour = attr['stroke']
    numSamples = int(pathLength * SAMPLES_PER_PX)
    for i in range(numSamples):
        #parametric length = ilength(geometric length)
        myPathList.append(path.point(path.ilength(pathLength * i / (numSamples-1))))
    myPaths[pathColour] = np.array(myPathList)
```

I've always felt that my Python ain't very Pythonic. Is there a way I can take advantage of some Python-ness to speed this up?

Comment: Replace the appropriate intialization and inner `for` loop with `myPathList = [path.ilength(pathLength * i / (numSamples - 1) for i in range(numSamples)]`.

Comment: If I had to guess, `ilength` is introducing a whole bunch of overhead you don't need to be repeated every time. I bet you can look at the implementation and do something very similar, but vectorized in numpy to accept an array of input lengths instead of a single point.

Comment: Alas, 5000 samples takes 13.1 seconds with `.append` and 13.4 seconds with the list comprehension, although I certainly appreciate the Pythoness. Suspect you're right about `ilength`. `cProfile` reports a lot of time spent in `path.py:994(derivative)` and `{built-in method scipy.integrate._quadpack._qagse}`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My solution was to sample N points using `path.point` and then interpolate those points using scipy spline and resample from the spline. Something like:

```
tck, _ = interpolate.splprep(pts, s=0)
result = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)
```

Where `pts` is a list of sampled points. The number N depends on how non-uniform the input curve is. Usually N=20 is sufficient for not too crazy cases:-)

Comment: Also ilength is ~1000 slower than point because computing arc length is not easy for bezier curves.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need to use the `ilength` method. What you are doing with `myPathList.append(path.point(path.ilength(pathLength * i / (numSamples-1))))` is computing the position of the point you want on the geometric length of the path, but since you know you are taking `numSamples` points regularly spaced on the path, you will keep the same number of points regularly spaced in the parametric distance, so you can directly write `myPathList.append(path.point(i / (numSamples-1)))`.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Does this give equidistant points?